# Replace XML Distinct-Values Oracle Service Bus 11G using Xquery

Tags: xml, replace, xquery, osb, distinct-values

How to replace XML result for distinct value case?

I get value `groupId` but I want to replace it into `groupName` which can be read by Customer and not only just Number.

```html
<TestList>
  <Test>
    <number>1000</number>
    <groupId>2323</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>2000</number>
    <groupId>3434</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>3000</number>
    <groupId>2323</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>4000</number>
    <groupId>4444</groupId>
  </Test>
</TestList>
```

Expected Result

```html
<TestList>
  <Test>
    <number>1000</number>
    <groupId>Group 1</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>2000</number>
    <groupId>Group 2</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>3000</number>
    <groupId>Group 1</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>4000</number>
    <groupId>Group 3</groupId>
  </Test>
</TestList>
```

Thanks,

Andree

Answer (score 0):

In 11g, I think you can use the BEA group by extension.  Try something like this:

```
declare variable $data :=
<TestList>
  <Test>
    <number>1000</number>
    <groupId>2323</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>2000</number>
    <groupId>3434</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>3000</number>
    <groupId>2323</groupId>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <number>4000</number>
    <groupId>4444</groupId>
  </Test>
</TestList>;

<TestList>{
  let $groups :=
    for $test in $data/Test
    group $test as $testGroup by $test/groupId as $groupId
    return
      <group>{$testGroup}</group>
  for $group at $pos in $groups,
      $test in $group/Test
  return
    <Test>
      {$test/number}
      <groupId>{$pos}</groupId>
    </Test>
}</TestList>
```